# Received an invalid header line: 'HTTP Strict-Transport-Security: default-src 'self';' in a C# console application

Tags: c#

Receiving an Invalid header exception in C# console application while accessing a web API.

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Received an
> invalid header line: 'HTTP Strict-Transport-Security: default-src
> 'self';'.)'

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var responseTask = httpClient.GetAsync("http://MYAPI");     
responseTask.Wait();
```

exception is thrown at `responseTask.Wait()`.

Not sure how to add the useUnsafeHeaderParsing as I have appsetings.json.
Adding a new app.config, application throws a run time exception.